# python3: .strip( ) not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, strip

I am parsing a file and want to strip the word Energy from the lines of the file but using `.strip("Energy")` doesn't yield the desired result and removed the 'E' of the 'Epoch'. I am probably not using the data types correctly or don't understand `.strip()` correctly. Please explain why am I getting the output given at the end of this post.
 
I have a **file** which looks like :

```
Epoch [20/20], Step 1,[1/3000], Loss: 7.2197, Energy: 0.2414, Prediction:-2.4456 

Epoch [20/20], Step 2,[2/3000], Loss: 0.6216, Energy: -0.2094, Prediction:0.5790
```

and I pass it through the following **code** in a `jupyter notebook`

```
with open(out_file) as f:
    for i in f:
        if i.startswith("Epoch"):
            row=str(i)
            print(row.strip("Energy")) # notice this line
```

which gives me the following **output** :

```
poch [20/20], Step 1,[1/3000], Loss: 7.2197, Energy: 0.2414, Prediction:-2.4456 

poch [20/20], Step 2,[2/3000], Loss: 0.6216, Energy: -0.2094, Prediction:0.5790
```

Comment: Please read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: Are you looking for str.replace("Energy", "")

Comment: @BlueRineS that would remove `Energy` from the middle of the line as well.

Comment: @eumiro so is that the desired behavior? or actually not?

Comment: Just do `' '.join(i.split('Energy:'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.strip()` docs: “Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing whitespace removed. If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.”. So it strips all `E`, `n`, `e`, `r`, `g`, and `y` characters from both ends. In your case the `E` from `Epoch`, but not the next `p` and not the digits from the end.

You can do:

```
if i.startswith('Energy'):
    print(i[6:])
```

to remove `Energy` from the beginning.

Comment: do you mean to say that substrings are removed only from the ends of the string and not from between ?

Comment: @fireball.1 yes, that's what `str.strip` does: “Return a copy of the string S with leading and trailing whitespace removed.” if you provide chars (like `"Energy"`) then it removes them instead. But still only leading and trailing ones.

Comment: can you add this line specifically to your answer as well for a more complete answer